# Apply shadow only when each of the red box shown after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I am new to canvas/jQuery. I wanted to apply shadow only when each of the red boxes are shown after the button is click. Currently it shows all the boxes have shadow even after the button is click or not clicked. Can I ask, is there any way I can do to make each box in red color Apply shadow? Thank you

Here can access the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-beaver-q9tcg?file=/index.html

```js
var data = [
  {
    name: "1",
    x: 20,
    y: 21,
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
    bgColor: "#00FF00",
    radius: 2,
    version: "1.0.0"
  },
  // for horizontal
  {
    name: "5",
    x: 110,
    y: 21,
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
    bgColor: "#00FF00",
    radius: 2
  }
];
var c = document.getElementById("NodeList");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  // loop through the data array
  const _data = data[i];
  ctx.beginPath(); // Call beginPath before drawing any shape
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.shadowColor = "white";
  // set initial blur of 3px
  ctx.shadowBlur = 3;
  ctx.fillRect(_data.x, _data.y, _data.width, _data.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";

  ctx.stroke();
}
$("#k").click(function () {
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // loop through the data array
    const _data = data[i];
    setTimeout(function () {
      ctx.beginPath(); // Call beginPath before drawing any shape
      ctx.fillStyle = "red";
      ctx.fillRect(_data.x, _data.y, _data.width, _data.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";

      ctx.stroke();
    }, 100 * i);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"
  ></script>
</head>
<body style="background: gray;">
  <canvas id="NodeList" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
  <button id="k">Hello</button>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: sample]

Comment: Hi , you are adding `ctx.shadowColor = "white";` line when you create boxes so its there by default in your canvas.

Comment: hi i already put the ctx.shadowColor = "white"; when the button click and remove it when i create boxes. however , i want to remove the shadow color of the first box when the second red box appear and the shadow should be applied only to second box. I add the image. it should be like when they click the button the first box will be red with shadow and then later will go to the second box. the second box will turn red with shadow while the first box will still red but without shadow

Comment: I see i am not sure how to do that(not good in canvas) will let you know if i found something :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. thanks a lot :) i've been trying to do it but the output still same.

Comment: Check if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ph5r1g4e/1/) helps you .

Comment: Hi ,the shadow color should not be in default.  the shadow color only appear when the red box shown. but if the box is turn black then the shadow should be remove also, i'm really sorry

Comment: Then , do like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/0h9yps6f/) . I know this is not perfect solution but , this will help you to proceed further .

Comment: this really helps me a lot. Thank you very much. Thank you. really appreciate your help. Really thanks a lot :)

Comment: Your welcome :-) .Try tweaking that code definitely it will lead to perfect solution :P

Comment: okay thank you so much again for your help. really Thanks a lot :D